# Regex satisfying several conditions

Tags: python, regex

Using python, I am trying to identify strings that verify the following conditions:

1. It must contain 9 characters
2. Characters 2 to 8 must be numbers
3. Characters 1 and 9 can be numbers or letters (lower or upper)
4. Characters 1 and 9 can't be both numbers.

For example, 'A12345678', '01234567A' and 'A1234567B' will match, but '012345678' will not match.

For conditions 1 to 3 I use `'([a-z]|[A-Z]|[0-9])[0-9]{7}([a-z]|[A-Z]|[0-9])$'`. For condition 4 I use `'(?![0-9]{9}$)'`. However, I don't know how to join those conditions in a unique regex. Can somebody help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I made I mistake, sorry. Condition 4 is that they can't be both numbers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Separate the two cases (letter in the front/letter in the back)

```
^([A-Z][0-9]{7}[A-Z0-9]|[A-Z0-9][0-9]{7}[A-Z])$
```

Apply with the "case insensitive" flag.

Comment: Thank you, that works! But adding that 1st and last can be both letters ```'^([A-Z][0-9]{8}|[0-9]{8}[A-Z]|[A-Z][0-9]{7}[A-Z])$'```

Comment: @JN_2605 Oh, that's right. See updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could try:

```
^(?=\D?\d{7,8}\D?$)[A-Z\d]{9}
```

See the online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/k6AGmq/16)

- `^` - Start string anchor.
- `(?=` - Open a positive lookahead.

  - `D?` - Optional non-digit.
  - `\d{7,8}` - 7 Or 8 digits.
  - `D?` - Optional non-digit.
  - `$)` - End string anchor and close positive lookahead.
- `[A-Z\d]{9}` - 9 Characters from the given class.

---

Or, assuming single string validation, you could try:

```
^(?!\d{9}|.*_|.+\D.)\w{9}$
```

- `^` - Start string anchor.
- `(?!` - Open negative lookahead:

  - `\d{9}` - Nine digits.
  - `|` - Or:
  - `.*_` - Any underscore anywhere in the string.
  - `|` - Or:
  - `.+\D.` - Any 1+ char followed by non-digit and another char.
  - `)` - Close negative lookahead.
- `\w{9}` - Nine word-characters.
- `$` - End string anchor.

Comment: That's clever, I like it. :)

Answer (score 0):

This

```
 r"^((?:[0-9]{8})(?:[a-z]|[A-Z])|(?:[a-z]|[A-Z])(?:[0-9]{8})|(?:[a-z]|[A-Z])[0-9]{7}(?:[a-z]|[A-Z]))$"

 # or with ignore case
 r"^([0-9]{8}[a-z]|[a-z][0-9]{8}|[a-z][0-9]{7}[a-z])$"
```

would match

```
(?:[0-9]{8})(?:[a-z]|[A-Z])             # 8 numbers + letter
(?:[a-z]|[A-Z])(?:[0-9]{8})             # letter + 8 numbers
(?:[a-z]|[A-Z])[0-9]{7}(?:[a-z]|[A-Z])  # letter + 7 numbers + letter
```

You can reduce it with the [`re.I` flag for case insensitivity](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.I).

I replaced the capturing groups with non-grouping groups.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/Nr5wus/3 and https://regex101.com/r/bypoGq/2 (ignore case)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a conditional in the regex pattern:

```py
^(?:([A-Z])|[0-9])[0-9]{7}(?(1)[A-Z0-9]|[A-Z])$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RyjuPl/3).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:([A-Z])|[0-9])` - either a letter (captured in Group 1) or a digit
- `[0-9]{7}` - seven digits
- `(?(1)[A-Z0-9]|[A-Z])` - if Group 1 matched, match a letter or digit, else, only match a letter
- `$` - end  of string.